# add mvc3 Unobtrusive validation Min/max validators

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to implement client validation for my custom type, however i'm not sure how to do it for min/max validators.

model:

```
[MultilanguagePropertyRequired(ErrorMessageResourceName = "fld_Description_val_Required", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Service.Controllers.Firm))]
[MultilanguagePropertyStringLength(1000, MinimumLength = 150, ErrorMessageResourceName = "fld_Description_val_MinLength_lbl", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Service.Controllers.Firm))]      
[Display(Name = "fld_Description_lbl", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Service.Controllers.Firm))]
public MultilanguageProperty<string> Description
{
    get
    {
        return this.GetMultilanguageProperty("Description", string.Empty, this);
    }

    set
    {
        this.SetMultilanguageProperty("Description", value);
    }
}
```

this is my custom string length attribute that extends "StringLegth":

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class MultilanguagePropertyStringLengthAttribute : StringLengthAttribute, IClientValidatable
{
    public MultilanguagePropertyStringLengthAttribute(int length) : base(length)
    {
    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        string strValue = (string)(value as MultilanguageProperty<string>).Value;

        return base.IsValid(strValue);
    }

    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        yield return new ModelClientValidationRule() { ValidationType = "multilanguagestringlength", ErrorMessage = this.ErrorMessageString };
    }
}
```

then on my view I have this:
..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function ($) {
        $.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.addBool("multilanguagerequired", "required");
        $.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.addMinMax("multilanguagestringlength", "minlength", "maxlength");
    } (jQuery));
</script>
```

..

which doesn't work. am i missing something here?
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am solving similar problem in a different way, but hey, try some parts of this code! I mean GetClientValidationRules() method for string length validation.

```
public sealed class MyStringLengthAttribute : StringLengthAttribute, IClientValidatable
    {
        private int? labelId;

        public MyStringLengthAttribute(int label, int maximumLength)
            : base(maximumLength)
        {
            labelId = label;
        }

        public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
        {
            if (labelId.HasValue)
            {
                return String.Format(MyLabel.Label(labelId.Value), name);
            }
            return String.Format(MyLabel.Default("FieldTooLong_Validation", "Field {0} is too long"), name);
        }

        public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
        {
            StringLengthAttributeAdapter adapt = new StringLengthAttributeAdapter(metadata,context, this);
            return adapt.GetClientValidationRules();
        }
    }
```

I use the Adapter class I found in .NET framework, and no need for the custom Javascript work.

And follow this if you still want to do custom JS part http://itmeze.com/2010/12/06/checkbox-has-to-be-checked-with-unobtrusive-jquery-validation-and-asp-net-mvc-3/

Answer (score 4):

No need to have a custom client side validation.  You can try something like this:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public sealed class ValidatePasswordLengthAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable {
    private const string _defaultErrorMessage = "'{0}' must be between {1} and {2} characters long.";
    private readonly int _minCharacters, _maxCharacters;

    public ValidatePasswordLengthAttribute(int minLength, int maxLength)
        : base(_defaultErrorMessage) {
            _minCharacters = minLength;
            _maxCharacters = maxLength;
    }

    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name) {
        return String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, ErrorMessageString,
            name, _minCharacters, _maxCharacters);
    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value) {
        string valueAsString = value as string;
        return (valueAsString != null && valueAsString.Length >= _minCharacters && valueAsString.Length <= _maxCharacters);
    }

    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context) {
        return new[]{
            new ModelClientValidationStringLengthRule(FormatErrorMessage(metadata.GetDisplayName()), _minCharacters, _maxCharacters)
        };
    }
}
```

It comes from the build-in MVC3 internet project template.

Answer (score 1):

I too am having the same problem.  You are missing ValidationParameters in your GetClientValidationRules:

```
    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
{
    var rule = new ModelClientValidationRule
                     {
                         ErrorMessage = this.ErrorMessage,
                         ValidationType = "dayrange"
                     };
    rule.ValidationParameters.Add("min", _minimumDays);
    rule.ValidationParameters.Add("max", _maximumDays);
    yield return rule;
}
```

I still having problems with the wiring between the jQuery.validator and jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.adapters but here's the code.  Hope it helps:

```
    $(function () {
      jQuery.validator.addMethod('dayRange', function (value, element, param) {
         if (!value) return false;
         var valueDateParts = value.split(param.seperator);
         var minDate = new Date();
         var maxDate = new Date();
         var now = new Date();
         var dateValue = new Date(valueDateParts[2],
                            (valueDateParts[1] - 1),
                             valueDateParts[0],
                             now.getHours(),
                             now.getMinutes(),
                             (now.getSeconds()+5));

         minDate.setDate(minDate.getDate() - parseInt(param.min));
         maxDate.setDate(maxDate.getDate() + parseInt(param.max));

         return dateValue >= minDate && dateValue <= maxDate;
    });

    jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.addMinMax('dayrange', 'minlength', 'maxlength', 'dayrange');

  }(jQuery));
```